# Why does Bintray Maven dependency snippet to copy include <type>pom</type>

Tags: java, maven

I just spend all day trying to figure out why I was not able to include [FontawesomeFX](https://bintray.com/dua3/public/FontAwesomeFX/9.1.2-jpms) to my Maven project. It turns out that the dependency to copy includes an extra line that prevented my maven eclipse project from downloading the dependency.

So why is `<type>pom</type>`  included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So why is `<type>pom</type>` included?

Perhaps an unsatisfying answer, but this looks like a bug in Bintray. The artifact is not of type `pom`, and the suggested syntax appears to be wrong. (The suggested Ivy snippet makes the same mistake.)

JFrog do not appear to have a public issue tracker to report this [without a support contract](https://jfrog.com/support/), but [they suggest](https://jfrog.com/support/) using the [`artifactory` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/artifactory).

For comparison, the [Central Repository shows](https://search.maven.org/artifact/de.jensd/fontawesomefx/8.9/jar) the correct form:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>de.jensd</groupId>
  <artifactId>fontawesomefx</artifactId>
  <version>8.9</version>
</dependency>
```

but [doesn't include versions since 8.10](https://bitbucket.org/Jerady/fontawesomefx#markdown-header-maven).

Comment: Oddly, this is the most satisfying answer. Imagine the amount of time someone spends trying to figure out what is wrong when you are just starting to learn about xml, maven, and now trying to get it from Bintray which requires me to have an additional file named settings.xml in a folder I didnt even know existed. You can imagine all the useless trouble shooting involved. Anyway I am glad this is a bug and I just hope that this thread pops up next time someone is in the same situation as me.